# How to use pg_trgm functions in JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq, pg-trgm

Is it possible to use [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html) functions as `similarity` in JOOQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever some vendor-specific feature is missing from jOOQ, use the plain SQL API:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/

Here's how to create a similarity function:

```java
public static Field<Double> similarity(Field<String> a, Field<String> b) {
    return DSL.field("similarity({0}, {1})", Double.class, a, b);
}
```